# Advertising my business as "Best XXXX Alternative"?

Tags: trademark, name, branding

I have a website on which I want to use the main keyword as "Best XXXX Alternative" wherein XXXX is the predominant competitor in my niche. As XXXX is searched a lot, I can build my SEO campaign and promote my website under the XXXX name. Consequently, people searching for XXXX will see my website on the first page of Google.

Can I use their name on my website's SEO titles?

XXXX is a pretty big corporation and I want to know if this is all right in terms of law? If not, how can I make it legal? E.g. showing prominently that we are not associated with XXXX?

Comment: Pespi has had large advertising campaigns stating that they're better than Coca-Cola explicitly by name and even using their logos, but they can afford to fend off whatever ultimately ineffective legal challenge Coca-Cola might attempt.

Comment: @RossRidge Yeah but I'm broke, what's the worst that could happen to me